# chrome not showing style source files in dev mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am using webpack, angular and boostrap.
I am trying to check scss code with chrome dev tools but I can't see the files, I just see the `<style>` tag. How can I modify scss or css directly with chrome.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Files that are compiled with webpack can be seen under `Sources -> webpack://`:

[image: Sample]

From here you can add breakpoints and even modify the files on-the-fly.

As for the CSS rules themselves, these can be modified through the F12 Developer Tools' `Elements` tab on the right-hand side under `Styles`.

Comment: Doesn't help at all, because I want to know which scss file I need to modify.

Comment: @RonaldVodnick you need to generated the source-maps files then only you can see the  original files

Comment: I just tak a starter project from github, how can I be sure it is generating?

Comment: Your initial question was **not** how to **find out** which files to modify based on a compiled file, but rather how to **inspect** the un-minified code. Given your newly-added image, the styles are being outputted **inline**. The best way to find out where these are coming from is by searching the project for one of the selectors. Also, if the content gets rendered out on the page the way you're expecting, then it is indeed generating. Depending what you're expecting to happen with the template, you can look at the HTML structure and rendered CSS rules to ensure the template is being applied.